# Preview of tikz/pgf in Lyx

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx, preview

I'm using tikz/pgf in Lyx. I included the `\usepackage{pgfplots}` in my header and the output pdf works fine. However, I'm using Lyx to be able to see a preview of my document as I write. Did anyone manage to get a preview of a pgf plot to work within Lyx?

Minimal example:
in Lyx:

\input{figure.tikz}

in figure.tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \draw[red] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw[red] (1,0) -- (0,1);
    \draw[blue] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It is not working with any other PGF/TiKZ so far. The pdf compiles, the preview option is activated (Tools→Preferences→Look & feel→Display).

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please post a minimal example. For more information, see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Does preview work for other PGF/TiKZ pictures?

Comment: When you say "in LyX: `\input{figure.tikz}`", do you mean you put the `\input` command manually in ERT, or you used insert->file in LyX? And what happens if you put the tikz code directly in an ERT; does the preview work then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the whole of the ERT containing the image (i.e. the box containing the PDF LaTeX code). Then on the main menu at the top choose Insert->Preview. Make sure you have instant preview turned on in preferences.

Comment: The preview option is activated under (Tools→Preferences→Look & feel→Display). [Lyx Help Page - Instant Preview](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/InstantPreview)

Comment: I edited the question. I still didn't get it to work.

Comment: Turns out that I wasn't patient enough, before. Seems that the conversion can take a while.

Comment: @Arne or anyone else reading this: You may find this doesn't work in LyX 2.1 or 2.2 running on Windows with MixTeX. See [this bug report](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10718#comment:3) for details. LyX 2.0 is not affected by this particular problem.